# How to combine items in list from a file?

Tags: python, list, file

I have a list in a text file as follows:

```
-[foo1
-[foo2
-[bar1
-[bar2
*etc*
```

How would I combine these items to simply print 'foo' and 'bar'?

I've tried something like

```
 data=open("file", 'r').readlines()
for n, line in enumerate(data):
if line.startswith("foo"):
    print "foo"
if line.startswith("bar"):
    print "bar"
```

Is there a better solution when there are a lot of these items that need combining?

Comment: Just wondering, why would it ever start with `foo` or `bar` when everything starts with `-[`? Shouldn’t it be `line.startswith(“-[foo”)` or something?

Comment: For clarification, can you provide an example of the expected output ?

Comment: If the file was set up like 'foo1
foo2
foo3
bar1
bar2
bar3
car1
car2
car3' The expected output is 'foo
bar car' I'm looking to aggregate the names and if possible, make it configurable so it could be changed in the future

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the first word on each line, and only want to print a given word once?

```
import re

def first_word(line):
    match = re.search("[A-Za-z]+")
    if match:
        return match.group(0)
    else:
        return None

with open("file.txt") as data:
    seen = {None}
    for line in data:
        word = first_word(line)
        if word not in seen:
            print(word)
            seen.add(word)
```

If you don't care about the order the words are printed in, you could simplify to

```
with open("file.txt") as data:
    words = set(first_word(line) for line in data)

words.discard(None)
print("\n".join(words))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input file looks like this:

```
foo1
foo2
foo3
bar1
bar2
bar3
car1
car2
car3
```

You could remove the numbers from the end of the word, count how many of that word are in the file, then print the words with how many times they appeared.

The code for that would look something like this:

```
data = open("list.txt").readlines()
items = []
item_count = []
for line in data:
    x = ''.join([i for i in line if not i.isdigit()]).replace("\n","")
    if x in items:
        y = items.index(x)
        item_count[y] += 1
    else:
        items.append(x)
        item_count.append(1)
for x in range(len(items)):
    print (items[x] + " * " + str(item_count[x]))
```

Which would give an output like this:

```
foo * 3
bar * 3
car * 3
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: very similar. I guess I'm looking to aggregate them further. The actual names aren't really foo and bar, I'm looking to aggregate them to  the first _ in the name listed in the file.